# Powershell duplicating file information

Tags: powershell

I'm writing an automation script that will make a backup of an XML file, parse the content to remove a certain word and replace with another, copy the completed file to a different directory. I've gotten it working for single files but if there's more than one file it's taking the content of ALL files in the folder and applying it to all. So, in example, I have 4 5kb XML's that get processed but on output side I end up with 4 20kb files. Any help would be awesome!

````
    Write-Log -Line "Files backed up. Editing..."
   (Get-Content -path '***\*.xml' -Raw) -Replace "DELETED", "DELISTED" | Set-Content -path 'c:\import\failed\*.xml'  
    Write-Log -Line "$QuarCount files edited. Reprocessing quarantine files..."
    Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\import\failed\*.xml' | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".xml","repro.xml"}
    move-item -path C:\Import\failed\*.xml -destination C:\Import\```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Content -path '***\*.xml'` is giving you the content of all xml files in the current path and its subdirectories at once.

You want to iterate over the files one by one:

```
Get-ChildItem -path '*.xml' -recurse | 
ForEach-Object { 
     $f = $_
    (Get-Content -path $f.FullName -Raw) -Replace "DELETED", "DELISTED" | 
    Set-Content -path "c:\import\failed\$($f.Name).xml"
}
```